# Can every stochastic $(\psi_n)$ process be mimicked by a measure preserving dyamics $f$ and a observable $\psi$, giving $\psi_n = \psi \circ f^n$?

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $(\psi_n)_{n \ge 0}$ a sequence of $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ valued measurable functions on $X$. Is it always possible to equip the measure space with a measurable and measure-preserving dynamical system $f: X \rightarrow X$ and measurable observable $\psi: X \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $\psi_n = \psi \circ f^n, $\mu$-a.e., \forall n \ge 0$?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about if we allow a different measure space?
Let the measure space be $\Omega = \overline{\mathbb R}^\infty$, the map $f =$ left shift on $\Omega$, map $\psi : \Omega \to \overline{\mathbb R}$ selects the first coordinate.  The measure on $\Omega$ is made from the joint distributions of the random variables $\psi_n$.  In fact there is a canonical measure-preserving map $X \to \Omega$ onto a subset of (outer) measure $1$ by $x \mapsto (\psi_n)_n$.  The difference from what is asked is that the left shift acts on $\Omega$ not on $X$.

Comment: If both $\Omega$ and $X$ are Lebesgue-Standard, then there is an invertible measure-preserving mapping $\Omega \to X$, which would allow one to define a $\mu$-preserving dynamical system $f$ on $X$ (conjugate to the shift on $\Omega$) and an observable $\psi$ as desired.

Comment: I'm confident I have an answer here (I've not yet checked the details, I'll do it later, for sure). Your answer seems so natural that makes me confident there is a motivation for every step of it. But I'm trying hard to get a deep intuition about it but I'm afraid I'm not getting there. First of all, your point is that $\psi_n = \psi \circ f^n \circ p$, $\mu$a.e., where $p$ is the canonical projection? Since $p$ may not be invertible, we may not have a similar equality for $\psi$ isolated (except under the hypothesis added by Blumenthal), right? Does it count for interpretation? Many thanks!

Comment: I was sketching an interpretation: say $\psi_n(x)$ is an outcome of the n-th trial of the experiment and $(\psi_n(x))_n$ is an outcome of the experiment. Then $\Omega$ is the set hosting all outcomes, whose probability is inherited from the experiment (the probability of $A \subset \Omega$ is equal to the probability that the experiment delivers an outcome in $A$), $f$ is going through the instances of the vector encapsulating experiments and $\psi$ is projecting the first entry of the encapsulating vector (as $f$ acts shifting it), that is $\psi \circ f^n$ is really $\psi_n$, "intuitively".

Comment: Blumenthal, thanks for your help too! I'm not aware what "Lebesgue-Standard sets" or "Lebesgue-Standard measure spaces" are. Google gave me no real tips. Could you explain what do you mean with that? Thanks.